# Linux Mint duplex driver for Samsung M2070

Tags: linux-mint, drivers, printing, samsung

I'm trying to print duplex on my Samsung M2070 Printer. I installed the driver from the Samsung website with the provided install.sh and then added the printer to the system in the Printers section of the System Preferences.

I see the Printer in LibreOffice Writer, and I can print with it, but there isn't a duplex function in the print window (On Win7 there is a Checkbox).

Do you have any ideas?

**Update**
I clicked on "Print" in LibreOffice and then "Properties" and "Paper". I saw the disabled duplex combobox. I thought on a driver issue, so i went to CUPS administration to check my driver. It wrote, that my driver is able to print duplex.

Answer (score 0):

The feature to print duplex is only available on Windows. It is very much a disgusting realization that the manufacturer refuses to implement such basic functionality for the operating systems. Sorry to give you the bad news.

Look here for the info: ( http://downloadcenter.samsung.com/content/UM/201512/20151211090911840/EN/English/English/manual/CACFBJHD.htm?keyword=duplex )

Good luck!